# Creating Nullables types in java

Tags: java, nullable

I am trying to create a nullalble object in Java but no idea how to do this , in C# this would be done like this

```
int? someTestInt;
```

This allows me to check for for null , while in certain cases i can use a 0 value ,this isnt always possible since certain execution paths allow 0 values

Comment: this a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985151

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but if you want to have an integer value that also can be declared `null`, you probably want to use the `Integer` class:

```
Integer nullableInteger = 1;
nullableInteger = null;
System.out.println(nullableInteger); // "null"
```

There are corresponding classes for each primitive: `Character`, `Long`, `Double`, `Byte`, etc. The 'standard library' numeric classes all extend the [`Number`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) class.

Note that Java [autoboxes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoboxing#Autoboxing) these objects automatically since JDK 1.5, so you can use *and declare* them just like the primitives (no need for e.g. "`new Integer(1)`"). So, although they are technically objects (and, therefore, extend the `Object` class, which the primitive `int` type does not), you can do basic arithmetics with them. They are converted to object operations at compile time.

Comment: Oh, great...you will get all the credit because you decided to go all out with code sample and everything... ;)

I'll give you +1 anyway.

Comment: In the west, it pays off to be fast with your draw :)

Comment: I dont need to use the nullable type for integers only ,will use the corresponding classes instead of the primitives , thanks for the info

Answer (score 3):

Java does not support nullable primitives.  You can use the Integer type if you want the ability to store nulls.

(This is a duplicate of this post:
[How to present the nullable primitive type int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985151/how-to-present-the-nullable-primitive-type-int-in-java))

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try the Integer type in Java.