# What is the Java equivalent for the following C# code?

Tags: c#, java

I have an interesting question. I understand the following C# code enables users to input null values in parameters:

```
public DateTime? date (DateTime dt) {}
```

What is the equivalent when coding in Java?

Comment: This method returns a nullable DateTime, but its argument isn't nullable.

Comment: The `c#` example allows a nullable DateTime to be returned. The DateTime being passed as the parameter cannot be null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Nullables types in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123544/creating-nullables-types-in-java)

Comment: So please elaborate why we would ever use the '?' in the code? I know that without it, an error will appear if I were to set dt = null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to present the nullable primitive type int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985151/how-to-present-the-nullable-primitive-type-int-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I recall correctly each object in java can be nullable.
Primitive types (`int, double, float, char` etc...) cannot be null. For using null with them you have to use their Object counterpart (`Integer, Double, Float...`)

Regarding dates, java.util.Date is an Object, so it can be null. Same goes for Calendar & GregorianCalendar.

equivalent code will be something like:

```
public Date date(Date dt) throws NullPointerException { 
  if (dt == null) throw new NullPointerException();
  ...
}
```

In C# you can use ? to allow null val in primitive types (e.g. to enforce object null reference errors). I don't understand why this thing bothers you. If you need for example a nullable integer parameter in java, you simply have to use `java.lang.Integer` and not primitive `int` type.

Comment: This question is really about updating my knowledge with C# and Java syntax and to simply understand best practice for setting nullable parameters. Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: C# and java are somewhat similar but still they are two different languages. There are some things you'll find in Java with no counterpart in C# and viceversa. My suggestion is not to compare syntax specific issues, but comparing them on functionality. Have a nice day.

Comment: Actually throwing NullPointerException is a runtime error while the C# syntax causes a compilation error if you try to pass null. Rather different things.

Comment: Sure, and honestly I prefer the Compile time check of C# against the runtime check of Java. However using the throw clause will make the compiler issue an error if you "forget" the try/catch (better than nothing IMO). On this side I prefer the java way to enforce catch block somewhere in your code. In C# you're not forced to catch (or am I recalling wrong?)

Answer (score 1):

Since a Date in Java is a class, a reference to it can already be null. In other words;

```
public Date date(Date dt) { }
```

...is Java's version of the same.

Note that the parameter also can be null in Java, which it can't in the C# version.

Comment: nope, in order to be equal you have to check the dt parameter and throw a NullPointerException if the given value is null (of course I'm joking :P)

Answer (score 0):

[How to present the nullable primitive type int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985151/how-to-present-the-nullable-primitive-type-int-in-java) says "Java does not have a nullable feature as C# has." Is that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support user-defined value types (e.g. types that can not be null).  In this regard, a Java DateTime object already supports nullable by virtue of allowing null to be assigned.

For other types, such as `int` and `double`, you can achieve the same effect by using the boxed versions `Integer` and `Double` which are allowed to be assigned null.