# How to write nullable int in java?

Tags: c#, java, nullable

I want to convert a web form to a model in Java.

In C# I can write this:

```
<input name="id" value="" type="text"/>


public class Test
{
    public int? Id{get;set;}
}
```

The `id` can be null.

But in Java when using struts2 it throws an exception:

```
Method "setId" failed
```

So how to write this case in Java?

Comment: use `Integer` instead of `int`.

Comment: Possible dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/q/985151/1015495 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1123544/1015495

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Instead of using `int` you can use `Integer` ([Integer javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)) because it is a nullable Java class.

Comment: thanks~ 'int' is same as 'Integer' in C#,so I didn't know this solution.

Comment: @Dozer don't forget to mark this post as an answer once the 15 mins have past.

Answer (score 52):

You can use an `Integer`, which is a reference type (class)in Java and therefore nullable.

`Int32` (or `int`) is a struct (value type) in C#. In contrast, `Integer` in Java is a class which *wraps* an `int`. Instances of reference types can be `null`, which makes `Integer` an legit option.

`Nullable<T>` in .NET gives you similar options because it enables you to treat a value type like a nullable type. However, it's still different from Java's `Integer` since it's implemented as a struct (value type) which can be compared to `null`, but cannot actually hold a genuine null reference.

Comment: this is a more thorough answer than the accepted one

Answer (score 9):

In Java, just use `Integer` instead of `int`.  This is essentially a nullable int.  I'm not too familiar with Struts, but using `Integer` should allow you to omit the value.

Answer (score 1):

[`Optional<Integer>`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) - The purpose of the class is to provide a type-level solution for representing optional values instead of null references.

[OptionalInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html) - A container object which may or may not contain a int value. If a value is present, isPresent() will return true and getAsInt() will return the value.