# Checking a nullable int causes problems

Tags: java, annotations, nullable

I have the following method:

```
public void myMethod (@Nullable int number) {
    if (number == null) {

    }
}
```

It results in a compiler error, saying that `null` and `int` cannot be compared. But `number` is marked with the `@Nullable` attribute! That means it *can* be null, right?

When I try to call the method with `null`, compiler error again. If that is the case, why can I mark the int nullable at the first place?

I just want to ask why can I mark an `int` nullable but I can't set it to null.

Comment: Instead of using an int, use the Integer class (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321175/how-to-write-nullable-int-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the int to Integer.
Null can be assigned only to Objects and not to the primitive types.
Use the wrapper class of int i.e. Integer.

In your case number should be not nullable, as its a primitive type and null can never be assigned to a primitive type.

Answer (score 1):

`@Nullable` is an annotation. Annotation is just metadata. You need something external to make it useful. The most you can do with annotations is specify what they can annotate. This is provided through `@Target` and the various `ElementType` enum constants.

Among those, is `PARAMETER` (the default is everything can be annotated). `PARAMETER` lets you annotate a method parameter. If you only set `PARAMETER` as the `@Target`, then the compiler will error if you try to use the annotation anywhere else. That's the most the compiler can give you on its own (YMMV for some built in annotation types).

In every other case, you need to build something that will process the annotation, either at compile time or at runtime. In this case, annotating that parameter with `@Nullable` is completely pointless.

Obviously, `int` is a primitive type. `null` is the only value for the null type which is assignable (or can be cast) to reference types. Primitives cannot be compared with reference types (except through boxing/unboxing operations).

So

```
someIntValue == null
```

is something that can be verified at compile time to be syntactically incorrect. This

```
@Nullable int number
```

cannot. It's just a parameter annotation.

Answer (score 1):

[Primitive data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) cannot be `null`. You can assign a `null` value to an object, but not to primitives; change it to [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) which wraps a value of the primitive type `int` in an object.

Answer (score 0):

This annotation is commonly used to eliminate `NullPointerExceptions`. `@Nullable` is often says that this parameter might be null.

see also https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/UseNullable (Google Guice)

In this lightweight dependency injection framework you tell that this dependency might be null. If you would try to pass null and without annotation the framework would refuse to do it's job.

reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html

Answer (score 0):

@Nullable is a type annotation and if you check the source of @Nullable(https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/source/browse/trunk/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/Nullable.java?r=24) and @NonNull(http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev/2.5.1/javax/annotation/Nonnull.java)

@NonNull is used in @Nullable and there is a condition which checks for null in @NonNull code as below:

```
if (value == null)
     return When.NEVER;
```

So the exception might be throwing here since int is a primitive type. This is expected to have strong type checking at compile time