# Compile protobuf to use primitive classes instead of well-known types

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protoc, proto3

Lets say I have test.proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "testing";
option java_outer_classname = "Test_v1";

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message TestMessage {
    .google.protobuf.Int32Value integerField = 1;
}
```

If I compile (using protoc v3.5.0) it to c# code I will get nullable type properties:

```
public int? IntegerField {
   get { return integerField_; }
   set { integerField_ = value; }
 }
```

But if I compile it to Java code, fields will be of well-known type:

```
public Builder setIntegerField(com.google.protobuf.Int32Value value) {
  if (integerFieldBuilder_ == null) {
    if (value == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    integerField_ = value;
    onChanged();
  } else {
    integerFieldBuilder_.setMessage(value);
 }
```

I am moving project from proto2 to proto3 so I would like to avoid using well-known types, because it will require a lot of work to change related code. With c# projects I will not require to modify anything but in Java I will need to do as in the following example:

```
TestMessage.Builder builder = TestMessage.newBuilder();
builder.setIntegerField(5); //<-- instead of this with proto2
builder.setIntegerField(Int32Value.newBuilder().setValue(5)); //<-- I will need to do something like this with proto3
```

Is there a way to compile `proto` file to Java so setters would accept primitive classes/wrappers (String, Integer, etc.) as parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is what to do when the value is missing. This isn't an issue with `int32` (in the .proto), as (in proto3, at least) an `int32` will always be there (defaulting to 0).  However, an `.google.protobuf.Int32Value` is a *message*, and as such it can be *missing*, ***or*** represent a value (which might be 0). In C# this concept can be neatly represented via `int?` (which can be `null`), but Java has no concept similar to `Nullable<T>`. The `Int32Value` encapsulates this, allowing a `null` reference.

So short version: no, and (^^^) that's why.

I assume you're actually replacing something that used to be:

```
message TestMessage {
    optional int32 integerField = 1;
}
```

???

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am replacing optional (in proto 2) to well-known type(in proto3). I am not very strong in Java, but as I understand in Java land int is primitive and Integer is wrapper that can be null. So what we have in [c# Nullable<int> might be the same as Integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321175/how-to-write-nullable-int-in-java). That's why I was expecting to see `Integer` instead of `Int32Value`. I can get expected result if I change field in `.proto` file to be `oneof`, but using `oneofs` is not an option.

Comment: @Reniuz yeah, that's a valid point - I can see how `Integer` would be fine there. I guess whoever implemented it just didn't want to do that, presumably to make it easier to provide expected `message` features rather than having to special-case `Integer`.

Comment: I posted question to [protobuf group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/8q27h5uCUtk) and got an answer. [Functionality was already requested](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2055) and the issue is still open. Thank you for your answer. I will accept it because the short version of an answer is correct :)