# declare a method that can except nullable Int or String in java (Android)

Tags: java, android

As per [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985151/how-to-present-the-nullable-primitive-type-int-in-java)..it is said that Java does not have a nullable feature as C# has. 
but i have seen many methods in Android Sdk that accepts 'null' as parameters for e.g see this method

```
SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
manager.sendTextMessage("address@example.com", null, "Message body here", null, null);
```

In the above `sentTextMessage` method, it is accepting `null` as parameters, i have a my method that accepts `String` as parameters i also want to pass `null` in some condition how can i do that ? in C# i can do `public void methodName(int? param1)` but in java how to do that..here is my method that should accept `null` also

```
public boolean update(long rowId,String status_receive,String status_send){/*xyz*/}

update(2,null,"yes") // error Invalid Argument,
```

My Question is how to declare a method that can accepts null values also ?

Comment: The invalid argument error is not coming from your passing the value `null` to a `String` argument.  If you are getting a stack trace, look at the line number on which the invalid argument exception was thrown.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you would use the wrapper classes in the `java.lang` package - e.g. `Integer` for `int`, `Long` for `long` etc. Auto-boxing will convert primitive values into objects where necessary - but be aware that this is different from .NET nullable types in that it *does* use full objects, rather than value types with an extra flag.

Answer (score 1):

Anything which is not a primitive type (int, byte, char etc.) can be null in Java. There is no need or possibility to declare anything on that.