# if(pause == null) { doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I use `if(pause == null)` to do something when `pause` is `null`. But I get the error

`the operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) long,null`

Here is the code,

```
public class Timer extends CountDownTimer {
    long pause = (Long) null;

    public Timer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        content.setText("Tijd over: " + millisUntilFinished / 100);
    }

    public void onPause(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if(pause == null) {
            pause = millisUntilFinished;
            content.setText("Tijd over: " + millisUntilFinished / 100);
            this.cancel();
        }
        else {
            this.start();   
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        content.setText("Tijd is op!");
    }
}
```

This class isn't finished, so ignore the rest of the code.

Comment: Try using `Long pause` instead of `long pause`.

Comment: why you complicate things, just use  , long pause = 0; and then when you test test if(pause == 0) {....} else { ... }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `pause` is a `long`, so `pause` can never be `null`, and the compiler is confused. Either make it a `Long`, or use some in-band indicator of invalidity.

Answer (score 7):

```
long pause = (Long) null;
```

should be

```
Long pause = null;
^
```

`long` is the *primitive type* but `Long` is the wrapper *object* of type `long`.

You may use a *sentinel* value instead of wrapping it as object.

```
long pause = -1;
...
if(pause == -1 ) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: As extra comment on _long pause = (Long) null;_, running it would be fun. Due to auto-unboxing you'd get a NullPointerException right there :)

Answer (score 4):

`long` with a lowecase 'l' is a primitive type in java, and you can not store `null` in it. Null can be stored only in references to classes. replace your `long` with `Long`, and it will work, because `Long` is a wrapper for the primitive, actually storing a reference, which can be null.

Please read:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 4):

`long` is primitive. It cannot be null. Only object references can be. If you really want to use null value for numbers change the type from 'long' to `Long`.

Answer (score 1):

`long` is a primitive type, it is not a `class` type and therefore `pause` is not a "reference" to an object, which means it cannot be `null`. If you want to be able to tell when the timer is paused, add a *flag* variable; a `boolean`.

You could change `long` to `Long` but that seems unnecessary, your code could be something like this and utilise a `boolean`:

```
public class Timer extends CountDownTimer {
    boolean isPaused = true;
    long pause = 0; // not sure what this is meant to store

    public Timer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        content.setText("Tijd over: " + millisUntilFinished / 100);
    }

    public void onPause(long millisUntilFinished) {
        if(!isPaused) {
            isPaused = true;
            pause = millisUntilFinished; // don't know what this is for
            content.setText("Tijd over: " + millisUntilFinished / 100);
            this.cancel();
            }
        else {
            this.start();
            isPaused = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        content.setText("Tijd is op!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The java language doesn't support the notion of nullable version of primitive types as C# does (see this question on [How to present the nullable primitive type int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/985151/5353)). So, you'll have to use the `Long` class wrapper instead of the `long` primitive type.

```
public class Timer extends CountDownTimer {
    Long pause = null;

    // Rest of the code ...
}
```

This will have a cost because the java runtime will have to box and unbox your value every time you access or update it. Depending on the usage of your code, this may degrade the performance of your application. This will need profiling.

Another option is to use a value that is "impossible" to represent an uninitialized `pause` field. If you know that `pause` will always be positive, then you can use `-1` to represent an uninitialized field.